# Android: Trying to implement " cant continue to next activity if edittext is empty", getting stuck

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement in android, a way to disable button to a next activity if the edit text field is empty e.g. username and password login screen.

Here is my code so far, thats crashing onclick of the submit button.
Its probably something simple but I just cant seem to see it today. Any help welcome, thanks

```
public class landingPage extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText username;
EditText passwordSave;
static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing);

    passwordSave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
}


public void submitPassword(View view) {
    if (passwordSave.equals("")) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view, "Please fill in your password", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Close", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });

        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);


        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        snackbar.show();
    } else {
    Intent addEntryIntent = new Intent(this, homePage.class);
    startActivity(addEntryIntent);

    finish();
}}
```

Here is logcat for the errors:

```
08-01 19:16:58.204 7380-7380/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.android, PID: 7380
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5273)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21225)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5514)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5273) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21225) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5514) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.android.landingPage.submitPassword(landingPage.java:33)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5273) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21225) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5514) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post logcat here.

Comment: I added them. sorry I forgot

Comment: You have a NullPointerException. Google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change **if condition** to this:

```
if (passwordSave.getText().toString().equals("")) {
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Other way to check if **edittext** is empty:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordSave.getText().toString().trim())) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view, "Please fill in your password", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Close", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });

        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);


        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        snackbar.show();
        return;
    } else {
    Intent addEntryIntent = new Intent(this, homePage.class);
    startActivity(addEntryIntent);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: That is an issue with the code, but that shouldn't cause the app to crash

Comment: Im getting red error "cannot resolve symbol getText"

Comment: @Yurtyya use getText()

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but its allowing me to progress and not catching the empty text field and showing the snackbar like I want it to, ill have to see why that is

Comment: @ Bruno, your update worked great, thanks very much. This way of doing it is new to me, Thanks.

Comment: @Yurtyya I'm here to help, if Works just acept answer to other people know that it Works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read through the stack trace, you'll notice that you've received a `NullPointerException`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

This means that your assignment for `passwordSave` returned `null`. Make sure you've correctly given the `EditText` that ID in the XML file and that you've spelled everything correctly.

On top of that is an issue with your if condition.

```
if (passwordSave.equals("")) {
```

`passwordSave` is a reference to the `EditText`, not to the text that user has typed. As @Bruno Ferreira said in his answer, you have to change the condition to

```
if (passwordSave.getText().toString().equals("")) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a slight typo in the ID on the xml, but now im not getting any errors, but its  its allowing me to progress and not catching the empty text field and blocking me moving to the next activity. The snackbar for "enter all fields" pops up for a second but it then moves on to to the next activity. Im not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing an EditText object with a String in your "submitPassword" method. 
Here is your error:

```
if (passwordSave.equals(""))
```

To get the string from your editText:
    passwordSave.getText().toString()